# HLSL rendering to larger than sceen target fails completely

Tags: directx, rendering, hlsl

Hi so im rendering a 3d scene using a hlsl shader if the output target size is less or equal to my window size everything works fine but if i try have it render to a 2x (renderscale) etc nothing shows up, if i try use opengl instead everything works fine, what reason could there be that the directx hlsl wont render anything to the target if size above the window size? hlsl version 9

Comment: After further testing the same applies on 2d with no depth buffer or test it just refuse to render using the directx shader while the opengl still works <.<

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the culprit was screen antialiazing that caused it